# Error al rutear imagenes usando gulp

Tags: gulp

Estoy aprendiendo gulp y me quede estancada en este error que me sale en consola con una imagen puesta en una plantilla

net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

no se si estoy ruteando mal mis enlaces de imagenes o algo en mi gulpfile esta mal

parte de mi gulpfile es este

```js
  
function style(){
    return gulp.src('./source/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function templates(){
    return gulp.src('./source/layouts/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
}

function images() {
    return gulp
        .src('source/images/*')
        .pipe(
        imagemin()
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'));
}

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch('source/sass/*.scss', style);
    gulp.watch('source/layouts/**/*.pug', templates);
    gulp.watch('source/images/*', images);
    gulp.watch('dist/**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}

function browser(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: './dist/'
    })
}
const watch = gulp.series(style, templates, images, gulp.parallel(watchFiles, browser));
exports.default = watch;
```

como mencione, estoy aprendiendo a programar y usar gulp
muchas gracias :)